# how to remove delimiters from MAC address in line

Tags: python

Hi I have a script that is processing a txt file line by line and the problem I'm having is that the input is not very consistent.   I have "cleaned up" much of it so it is consistent in this form:

```
172.31.8.72|web302-eth0|172.31.8.72|52|54|00|58|74|E9|web302
```

However, though I have achieved consistency, I'd like to remove the "|" (pipes) from the MAC address.  so that it looks like:

```
172.31.8.72|web302-eth0|172.31.8.72|5254005874E9|web302
```

I could use some help please :)

Here is the function in my script that is doing this processing (so far) I know I'm close!
Any help is greatly appreciated!  :)

```
def processScan():
  with open(latest_file, "r") as scanInput:
    with open(pingOutput, "w") as pingOnly:
      with open(assetOutput, "w") as knownAssets:
        with open(assetVsRT, "w") as assetRTdiff:
          for record in scanInput:
            ppattern = '[0-9] PING'
            khpattern = '^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+.*\s+\d'
            if re.search(ppattern, record):
              record = re.sub("PING only", "PING-Only", record.strip())
              record = re.sub(" ", "|", record.strip())
              pingOnly.writelines(record + "\n")
            elif re.search(khpattern, record):
              record = re.sub('"', '', record.strip())
              record = re.sub("  ", " ", record.strip())
              record = re.sub(" ", "|", record.strip())
              knownAssets.writelines(record + "\n")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the files have the same format? I'm asking because possibly you can do it in more structured manner. Regexps are not the best tool for all problems. Like in the joke: if you have a problem and want to solve it with regexps  - congradultion, you have 2 problems now. It seems like you can work with the files like with csv with `|`-delimeter. Python's stdlib has the `csv` module to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using Regex, so use some more!

```
re.sub('\\|([A-F0-9]{2})\\|([A-F0-9]{2})\\|([A-F0-9]{2})\\|([A-F0-9]{2})\\|([A-F0-9]{2})\\|([A-F0-9]{2})\\|', '|\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6|', record)
```

The pattern is long because you need the results of all the captures and repeated captures are overwritten.

Comment: Thank you!  It works beautifully!  I'm new to Python and a little rusty on my regex, but your solution is amazingly simple!  Hope this helps someone else too!  :)